# Accessing a variable from player prefs in another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm managing my HighScore in my scene "Standard Game" by using playerprefs

I need to access my variable HighScore in my other script "SaveTest" which is in a different scene called "Main Menu" So i can destroy objects tagged DestroyUI when a highscore is reached.

Ive been googling for a bit but im not sure what im doing wrong.

**Save Test**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
public ButtonReposition buttonrepositionscript;

void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("ButtonReposition");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (GetComponent<ButtonReposition.highscore <= 100)

    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("DestroyUI"));
}
}
```

**HighScore script**

```
public class ButtonReposition : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button prefab;
public GameObject loseObject;
public int count;
public int highscore;
public Text countText;
public Text Highscoretext;
public Image lineimagestandard;

// Use this for initialization

void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scorePref");
    highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scorePref");
    SetHighscoretext();
    SetCountText();
    float x = Random.Range(325f, -600f);
    float y = Random.Range(250f, -450f);
    Debug.Log(x + "," + y);
    prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Highscoretext.name == "highscoretext")
    {
        Highscoretext.text = "highscore" + highscore;
    }

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scorePref", highscore);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this on your Save Test script `highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("scorePref");`
and that's it.